# Entity Framework fluent mapping foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have these entity classes (simplified):

```
public class MyClass 
{
      int Id {get;set;}
      int MyObjectId {get;set;}
      MyObject MyObject {get;set;}
}

public class MyObject 
{
      int Id {get;set;}
      string Name {get;set;}
      ICollection<MyClass> MyClass {get;set;}
}
```

Fluent mapping

```
HasRequired(x => x.MyObject).WithMany(x => x.MyClass)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MyObjectId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I am just starting to learn EF, so I have two questions

Can I avoid using `MyObjectId` to tell EF how to map things or should I get rid of `MyObject` class inside `MyClass` and use `MyObjectId` instead, and whenever I need that nested data from table I should pull it by MyObjectId? As at this point it doesn't feel right to have both.

Fluent api requires me to have reference to `MyClass` in `MyObject` just to specify `WithMany` property, I actually don't need access to `MyClass` from `MyObject` - any guidance?

I guess I am used to nHibernate...

Comment: Have you come across the `[ForeignKey]` attribute?

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about fluent api thing, is that the downside of using it?

Comment: Is your question related to querying or creating the db?

Comment: I think both, I still need valid mapping to create db, but in terms of querying I don't want MyClass to have MyObjectId and MyObject as I can access to MyObject.Id that makes no sense to keep both, unless this is how EF is supposed to work.
Maybe I am doing it absolutely wrong and my Entities shoud not contain complex objects, just db replication. This would involve automaper to pull data from other entities and map results to viewModel

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here:

[Entity Framework fluent mapping foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943122/entity-framework-fluent-mapping-foreign-key)

See the section "Renaming a Foreign Key That Is Not Defined in the Model"

BTW long ago I tried defining my models with navigation properties only (no FK).  I don't remember exactly why I gave up on that but I ran into problems and wound up putting FK's on all my entities.  That is just my experience others may tell you differently.